# Parsing JSON RFC Grammar

Tags: json, parsing, context-free-grammar, context-free-language

I am learning to build parsers and thought maybe I should start with a simple one such as JSON. I was looking at the JSON grammar published in this [RFC document](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-2).

The JSON grammar shown there looks like what's shown below. What kind of notation is this, and how can I generate/write a parser for this?

```
JSON-text = ws value ws

begin-array     = ws %x5B ws  ; [ left square bracket

begin-object    = ws %x7B ws  ; { left curly bracket

end-array       = ws %x5D ws  ; ] right square bracket

end-object      = ws %x7D ws  ; } right curly bracket

name-separator  = ws %x3A ws  ; : colon

value-separator = ws %x2C ws  ; , comma


ws = *(
      %x20 /              ; Space
      %x09 /              ; Horizontal tab
      %x0A /              ; Line feed or New line
      %x0D )              ; Carriage return

value = false / null / true / object / array / number / string

      false = %x66.61.6c.73.65   ; false

      null  = %x6e.75.6c.6c      ; null

      true  = %x74.72.75.65      ; true

object = begin-object [ member *( value-separator member ) ]
               end-object

member = string name-separator value

array = begin-array [ value *( value-separator value ) ] end-array

number = [ minus ] int [ frac ] [ exp ]

decimal-point = %x2E       ; .

digit1-9 = %x31-39         ; 1-9

e = %x65 / %x45            ; e E

exp = e [ minus / plus ] 1*DIGIT

frac = decimal-point 1*DIGIT

int = zero / ( digit1-9 *DIGIT )

minus = %x2D               ; -

plus = %x2B                ; +

zero = %x30                ; 0

string = quotation-mark *char quotation-mark

char = unescaped /
  escape (
      %x22 /          ; "    quotation mark  U+0022
      %x5C /          ; \    reverse solidus U+005C
      %x2F /          ; /    solidus         U+002F
      %x62 /          ; b    backspace       U+0008
      %x66 /          ; f    form feed       U+000C
      %x6E /          ; n    line feed       U+000A
      %x72 /          ; r    carriage return U+000D
      %x74 /          ; t    tab             U+0009
      %x75 4HEXDIG )  ; uXXXX                U+XXXX

escape = %x5C              ; \

quotation-mark = %x22      ; "

unescaped = %x20-21 / %x23-5B / %x5D-10FFFF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As specified in section 1.1 of the linked RFC, the formalism is that of RFC 5234, Augmented BNF for Syntax Specifications (ABNF):

> The grammatical rules in this document are to be interpreted as described in [RFC5234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5234).

To build a parser, you could use that as a specification and implement it in an ad hoc manner in the language of your choice, or you could translate into a format recognized by available lexer/parser generators.